# convert string value to SqlDbType

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm building an in-memory data dictionary out of these class objects

```
public class DDRow
{
    public string ColumnName { get; set; }
    public SqlDBType DataType { get; set; }
    public int ColumnSize { get; set; }
    public bool IsIdentity { get; set; }
    public bool AllowDBNull { get; set; }
 }
```

...in a subroutine, populating it from a SqlReader.GetSchema call

```
//Retrieve column schema into a DataTable.
     schemaTable = myReader.GetSchemaTable();
     DDRow wrkRow = null;
     //For each field in the table...
      foreach (DataRow myField in schemaTable.Rows)
       {
            wrkRow = new DDRow(); 
            wrkRow.ColumnName = Convert.ToString(myField["ColumnName"]);  // string
            wrkRow.DataType = myField["DataType"];   //SqlDbType
```

...which all seems to work except I can't figure out how to convert

```
myField["DataType"]
```

which is an object, into a SqlDBType value to put into DDRow.DataType

I can convert it into a string:

```
   string s1 = Convert.ToString(myField["DataType"]);
```

But

```
   SqlParameter p = new SqlParameter(s1, o);
   SqlDbType q = p.SqlDbType;  // <-- error here.
```

throws an error as indicated above, so the string is not enough.

I recognize I might be able to run the string value through a conversion table routine to produce the SqlDbType value; is there any shorter way?

EDIT -------
- in light of adam's answer below, this is the correct way to code it, and the correct way to test that the right result was produced (replaces DataType with ProviderType in the DDRow
definition)

```
  wrkRow.ProviderType = (SqlDbType)(int)myField["ProviderType"];

  SqlParameter wrkS = new SqlParameter("@ABC",wrkRow.ProviderType,8);

  SqlDbType wrkT = wrkS.SqlDbType;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DataType field is the CLR type - not the SqlDbType. The ProviderType field is the one you are after. It is an int that represents the SQL Server data type. You can cast that to a SqlDbType easily. Below is an example that should fit in with your code:

```
var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
var schemaTable = reader.GetSchemaTable();
var fields = new List<DDRow>();

foreach (DataRow myField in schemaTable.Rows)
{
    fields.Add(new DDRow()
    {
        ColumnName = Convert.ToString(myField["ColumnName"]),
        DataType = (SqlDbType)(int)myField["ProviderType"]
    });
}
```

Then you can do this to create your SqlParameter (assuming that your variable 'o' is the column name).

```
var field = fields.First();

SqlParameter p = new SqlParameter("@" + field.ColumnName, field.DataType);
SqlDbType q = p.SqlDbType;
```

In your example so seem to be passing the parameters the wrong way around too. Also in your class example, the DataType field should be SqlDbType rather than SqlDBType

Comment: Thanks, that works.  SqlDBType was a typo when I built the question. Not sure what you meant by wrong way around, as the correct result in DDRow seems to be produced.

Comment: That's great. In your post you seemed to pass s1 as the first parameter - which was the name of the data type if I'm not mistaken, but it should have been the parameter name. I've edited my answer to include the "@" symbol as I forgot to put that in there. Either way, what you are doing now looks fine.